# Custom Popup focusout event

Tags: jquery, focus

I have a  custom pop-up that is shown at a click of a button.

The pop=up should close when I click outside it (focusout) and should not close when I click inside of the pop-up. It works beautifuly but I have a problem when I move items from one list to another inside the pop=up. In this case the focus is lost and the pop=up close. I want it to remain open.

My actual implementation

```
> http://jsfiddle.net/7fsxr2ed/6/
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In $(popupSelector).focusout() function just comment below line

```
 $(popupViewSelector).hide();
```

I have updated fiddle and link is http://jsfiddle.net/7fsxr2ed/8/

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I propose this solution. Try

```
function createPopup(triggerSelector, popupViewSelector, popupSelector, showCallback, hideCallback ) {    
    var $trigger = $(triggerSelector);
    var $popupView = $(popupViewSelector);

    $trigger.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($popupView.is(':visible')) {
            $popupView.hide();
            if(hideCallback) {
                hideCallback();
            }
        } else {
            $popupView.show();
            if(showCallback) {
                showCallback();
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click.popup', function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);

        if(!$target.closest($popupView).length && !$target.closest($trigger).length) {
            $popupView.hide();
            if(hideCallback) {
                hideCallback();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7fsxr2ed/9/

Comment: Oh... I forgot add $(document).off('click.popup'); on hide

Comment: It looks like your fiddle example is working. I wonder why I need $(document).off('click.popup') on hide ? and where to put it actually ?

Comment: if you will use function createPopup at some places at page... you need add off('click.popup') on hide http://jsfiddle.net/7fsxr2ed/10/

Comment: Ok but in this last example when you try to open close the pop-up two times it is not working when I click outside